# Interface for two similar classes

Tags: java, exception, interface

I have a problem with interfaces which I have to write. In our company project we have one class which provide some web methods like: logIn, reporting, addNote and different. Every method throw exception which was wrote by someone (probably the same person which wrote this class).
Now I have to write "equivalent" of this class (using web services) and write interface for both classes. But my class doesn't throw any exception (I don't write throwing exception in signature, I used try-catch block to handle with this exception). Is there any simple way to write interface for both classes (which has different signatures because of that exception)? Or I have to rewrite this first class and use in it try-catch block (or modifie my class). I would like to avoid this situation...

Comment: If your class method throws exception then the method of the interface which is implemented by your class should have the method which throws exception.

Answer (score 2):

> (I don't write throwing exception in signature, I used try-catch block to handle with this exception)

That sound like a misuse of exception handling ... unless your code can *really* deal with all of those exceptions.  The correct thing to do with an exception is to allow it to propagate to a point further up the cakll stack that can deal with it *properly*.

But either way, you can write an common interface where the methods are declared as throwing the exceptions.  In your version of the class, simply leave the exceptions out of the signature; e.g.

```
public interface Foo {
    public void bar() throws SomeException;
}

public class OldFoo implements Foo {
    public void bar() throws SomeException { ... }
}

public class NewFoo implements Foo {
    public void bar() { ... }
}
```

It is legal Java for an interface method to throw an exception, and an implementation of that method to not throw it.

Comment: Yes, it works! That's what I need :) Thank for your help. But is that a bad practise or not?

Comment: Nope.  It is not bad practice to do that.  However, it >>is<< bad practice to catch exceptions in places where you can't deal with them properly.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of your method defined in your interface must have the exception defined.
In other words the exception is part of the signature.

Comment: So, I have to change this first class which has information about throwing exception or add to my class methods this exception? Is there some kind of "see around" of this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If one of the concrete implementations throws an exception, and the other catches it, unfortunately you cannot use the same interface. The exception is part of the method definition, and if two methods handle exceptions differently, then they are not the same. So, you will have to modify one of the classes I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

you can only override the methods declared in the interface to throw the same exception or a derived type Exception , i mean you can't have you implemented methods to not throw any exception , whilst in your interface the methods are described to throw a specific exception .